# How to test if code runs in other appdomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I've written the following code to try to execute code in another appdomain, but how do I test if it actually is executed in the other appdomain?

```
AppDomain a = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
CompilerParameters cp1 = new CompilerParameters();
string program1 = "using System; public class A{ public A(){}}";
ObjectHandle handle = a.CreateInstanceFrom(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,     "DOTNETCOMPILERa.RommelClass");
RommelClass test = (RommelClass)handle.Unwrap();
CompilerResults cr = test.test(program1, cp1);

AppDomain.Unload(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can e.g. evaluate the [`FriendlyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`Id`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.id(v=vs.110).aspx) of [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain(v=vs.110).aspx). It should return different values depending on the appdomain it runs in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I debug and step through I can confirm that inside test.test() I have a different currentdomain:)